# NSMutableDictionary for JSON

Tags: ios, xcode, json, nsmutabledictionary

i'm stuck with a problem!

I have a String with JSON like:

> {"UserName":"username","PassWord":"password"}

I build this JSON string with xcode like:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     [jsonDict setValue:self.usernameField.text forKey:@"UserName"];
     [jsonDict setValue:self.passwordField.text forKey:@"PassWord"];
     NSLog(@"Dict: %@",jsonDict);

     NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"JSON String: %@",jsonString);

     NSString *postStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonString];
```

But now i want a string with JSON like:

```
{ "comp": [
  { "id": "1" },
  { "id": "2" },
  { "id": "3" }
 ],
"contact": [
  { "mail": "some@email.com", "name": "Name"  },
  { "mail": "email@email.com", "name": "Name"  }
 ]
}
```

But how can i do this? Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you comp. Using what you have and this example, you should be able to get contact easily.

```
NSDictionary *id1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"1", "id", nil];
NSDictionary *id2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"2", "id", nil];
NSDictionary *id3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"3", "id", nil];

NSArray *ids = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:id1, id2, id3, nil];

NSDictionary *comp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ids, @"comp", nil];
```

Also, check out the following library for easy serialization/deserialization.
[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)